# How to identify position in a list to insert div

Tags: javascript, list, html, reference, position

In my app, I am appending a list of divs (html) to a parent div container

```
muse_card_template = $("#mustache.muse_card").html()
html = Mustache.to_html(muse_card_template, muse.getMustacheJSON())

html = "<li class=''>" + html + "</li>"
@$('.muses_card_container').append (html)
```

[image]

```
//div to which I append my cards
.content
  %ul.muses_card_container
```

So essentially I am just appending a list of divs to a div and wrapping it by setting the width of the container.

My intention is to expand the detailed contents of the card after I click, and the expanded view should be displayed right below the card that was clicked (expand inline below).

However currently I do not have any reference as to where to insert the expanded content as I only have a list of divs.

Are there any libraries that I can use to identify the position to insert my new div? Or any code changes I can do to make this work?

EDIT:

Added expected result

[image]

The challenge in doing this is that I do not know where to insert the expanded content when the user clicks on an image.

My code for looping the HTML image cards is as follows:

```
addAll: ->
  @options.muses.each(@addOne)

addOne: (muse) ->
  #render corresponding muse cards
  muse_card_template = $("#mustache.muse_card").html()

  #html for cards are rendered via Mustach
  html = Mustache.to_html(muse_card_template, muse.getMustacheJSON())

  #append resulting html to 'muse_card_container' div
  html = "<li class=''>" + html + "</li>"
  @$('.muses_card_container').append (html)
```

Comment: Can you put the iterating loop around that code you've given please? And give us the HTML contents of muse_card_template

Comment: @popnoodles, i updated the original post with the expected result and more code. Is the HTML code necessary? I can paste it but not sure how that will help.

Comment: Well right now nobody but you knows the code that iterates through those elements so nobody but you can see the unique identifier  and nobody but you knows the HTML of the template so nobody but you can utilise that identifier (that they can't see) to help you with this.

Comment: **♪Nobody♪ ♫but♫ ♪you♪**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming here that you can use JQuery.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/UgBmf/2/ (Click on the boxes for the details)

To know where to insert the details, we first need to know the li which was clicked

`event.target` gives us the li which was clicked in my code. (Since I added the click handler to ul instead of adding it to each li)

`.index()` returns you the index of our current li in the list of all the LIs. (zero based position) Reference: http://api.jquery.com/index/

If `numOfLIsInARow` is the number of LIs in a row,  then `index - (index % numOfLIsInARow) + numOfLIsInARow - 1` returns the position of the LI after which the details LI/DIV needs to be added. You can get the LI using `.get()` method.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing you have jQuery already. Attach a click event handler to each of the li elements. When the click event is fired, the event object will have the details about where the click originated from.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').each(function(index, element){    
    $(element).click(function(event){     
      $('#text').text($(event.target).html());
    });
  });
});
```

Look at this [code snippet](http://jsbin.com/eqajir/5/watch). click on the numbers on the right hand pane, you'll see the number you clicked on displayed below in a label.

Comment: why .each then .click? You can just `$('li').click()`

Comment: Well, an array is returned since there are multiple li elements. I am not entirely sure if I can call click on array and never bothered to look for it, just assumed that one can't call click on an array. I could be colossally wrong though.

Comment: `.click()` iterates just as `.each()` does. `$('#unique')` would be an array  even though there'd be only one element. You wouldn't do this `$('#unique').each(function(){$(this).click(function(){...});});`

Comment: either way, this just tells you the element you clicked, not where to show the expanded content as per the question

Answer (score 2):

The solution is depend on how you display these cards, as I asume from your code these cards either floated or have `display:inline-block` property set. If this is the case then you might try the following algorithm to determine where to insert card's description:

The idea is to push the cards beneath selected card, to do so you should insert a new element (also floated or with inline-block) after the last card in the row, this element should have the width of the card's container to take the whole row and push the cards below it. Now all you need is to determine after which card is to insert this "pusher-element": given that the all cards have the same width it's possible to calculate how many columns you have and then get the index of the clicked card, get it column and insert the "pusher" after the last card in the row this element in.

```
elementsInColumn = 4 # you should calculate it based on cards and container width 
$('.muses_card_container li').click ->
    index = $('.muses_card_container li').index(this)
    indexInColumn = index % elementsInColumn # get card index in column (0..elementsInColumn-1)
    lastCardInColumnIndex = index + (elementsInColumn - indexInColumn) #
    lastCardInColumn = $('.muses_card_container li').get(lastCardInColumnIndex)
    $(expandedContentHTML).insertAfter(lastCardInColumn)
```

I haven't tested this code but you may got the idea

UPD: Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/azgSX/1/

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest just to find the item which is positioned furthest to the right after the one you clicked, as that will be at the end of the current row and you can move the details after that. This also means you don't need to have a set number of cards per row so works with different screen sizes.

You can use [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetLeft) to check the position, [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to loop through the items, and [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)/[insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to move the expanded details element.

**Core code**

```
// Note: 'this' is the card which got clicked

// find next right-most li by looping the items after this one
var leftPos = this.offsetLeft;
var rightMost = $(this);

while (true) {
  // get the next li
  var nextLi = rightMost.next();
  if (nextLi.length == 0 || nextLi[0].offsetLeft <= leftPos) {
    // if we have reached the end one or the next li is farther left, we are at the end of the row
    break;
  } else {
    // nextLi is currently the furthest right
    rightMost = nextLi;
  }
}

// move details from its current place to after the end of the row
var detailsLi = $('#details');
detailsLi.detach();
detailsLi.insertAfter(rightMost);
```

Basic working example at http://jsfiddle.net/7dGfg/2/ This uses LIs as per Alexander's sample but the same principle applies with divs, as long as each card is the same size.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the HTML5 data attributes(they are ignored by the rendering engine) like so:

```
<div id="mustache" class="muse_card" data-row="2" data-bottom="false"></div>
```

and

```
$("#mustache.muse_card").click(function(){
    if(this.get()[0].getAttribute('data-bottom'])){ // only insert the content on top if it is in the bottom row. 
        // Do something to insert the content in between this.get()[0].getAttribute('data-row') (in this case 2) and this.get()[0].getAttribute('data-row') +- (in this case 1)
    }else{ // This is not in the top row.
        // Do something to insert the content in between this.get()[0].getAttribute('data-row') (in this case 2) and this.get()[0].getAttribute('data-row') +1 (in this case 3)
    }
})
```